# How to get the element in BufferedImage [ ]?

Tags: arraylist, bufferedimage

I created a program that display images on JTable, so I used `BufferedImage [] images`. I used the following code to store my images in the `images`. The program has successfully shows the images on JTable.

```
int indexFile=0;
String[] fileNames = {"img1.jpg", "img2.jpg","img3.jpg"};
BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[fileNames.length];
for(int j = 0; j<images.length; j++)
try {
   fileNo =fileNames[indexFile];   
   path = "/myJava/resources/"+fileNo;                  
   URL url = myClass.class.getResource(path);
   images[j] = ImageIO.read(url);
   indexFile++;
}
```

I want to get the value of the element in `images`, so I used the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(images[i])  // I am expecting output like "img1.jpg"
}
```

My problem is, it gives me the following output instead of (e.g. img1, img2, img3).

```
BufferedImage@e691ea46: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@cd292449 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 607 height = 509 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
```

How can I get this output? ---> img1.jpg
Thank you.

Comment: There is no connection between a `BufferedImage` and the file it was read from. So what you are trying to do, is not directly possible. Is there a reason you can't just print the names from `fileNames`? Another option is to wrap the filename and the image into a custom class, with a `fileName` and an `image` field.. Should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Actually it's a drag and drop program. I created a JTable with 1 row, 5 columns. Each cells I filled with images from the " bufferedImage images [ ]". The program allows user to 'rearrange'  the image by drag and drop. Finally, I want to get the image file name of each cells. e.g. cell 1="img3.jpg", cell 2="img1.jpg"..etc. I tried these code 'table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column)' and  'images[i]'. But both doesn't work.